# Sql Server Event_Type of suspect_pages after restoring

Tags: sql-server

I got a database corruption. At that time, the event_type for that database is 1 (An 823 error that causes a suspect page (such as a disk error) or an 824 error other than a bad checksum or a torn page (such as a bad page ID))

I use a back up file to restore that database, I can see that the event_type for that database is 4 now (Restored (page was restored after it was marked bad)).

So my concern is if this database is really recovered from corruption?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to confirm there is no corruption any longer is to do a DBCC CHECKDB or a DBCC CHECKTABLE (if you know the table(s) that were corrupted).  This will validate that corruption is gone.